Variable With Class Object Value Accessed Multiple Time is Unexpected Modified in Laravel
so i have a problem while accessing variable that contain class object as a value, if i call it multiple time, it will change result. here the example:
// declared on the first line
$preparedSpec = Specialization::query();

// call on another line like this
$availableSpecializations = $preparedSpec->pluck('name')->toArray();

// call it again under $availableSpecializations
$specDoesntExist = $preparedSpec->where('id', $spec)->doesntExist();

the problem exists when i do this:
$existedSpecIds = $preparedSpec->whereIn('name', $existed)->get();

expected result of variable $existedSpecIds should return data collection, but return empty array []
i don't really understand why this happen, may be some expert can explain?
i have already try to initiate new class instead reusing it on $preparedSpec variable, and of course it works.
and actually i just curious why that happen.

The issue arises from the fact that you're modifying the same query builder:
$preparedSpec = Specialization::query();

instance multiple times, which accumulates all the modifications and affects subsequent calls
Try this Instead:
// Initial Query
$preparedSpec = Specialization::query();

// First Call
$availableSpecializations = (clone $preparedSpec)->pluck('name')->toArray();

// Second Call
$specDoesntExist = (clone $preparedSpec)->where('id', $spec)->doesntExist();

// Third Call
$existedSpecIds = (clone $preparedSpec)->whereIn('name', $existed)->get();

clone will help you create a separate copy of the $preparedSpec query builder for each operation. This ensures that each query remains unaffected by changes made in other queries.

Create new query builder for each variable because query builder is mutable
This should work
$availableSpecializations = Specialization::query()->pluck('name')->toArray();

$specDoesntExist = Specialization::query()->where('id', $spec)->doesntExist();

$existedSpecIds = Specialization::query()->whereIn('name', $existed)->get();

